# I am getting "error: no member named 'async' in namespace 'std' " when compiling using MakeFile

Tags: c++, makefile, std, gnu-make

When I run command `clang++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 main.cpp` in terminal the file gets compiled successfully.

```
% clang++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 main.cpp
% ./a.out                             
s
s
%
```

But when I try to do the same thing using MakeFile. I get following error.
I don't know why error occurred when same command is executed in both case.

```
% make main
c++     main.cpp   -o main
main.cpp:17:5: warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    auto s = std::async(get);
    ^
main.cpp:17:19: error: no member named 'async' in namespace 'std'
    auto s = std::async(get);
             ~~~~~^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

My MakeFile content:

```
main: main.cpp
    clang++ -Wall -g -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

My main.cpp content:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<string>
#include<future>

std::string get() {
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    return s;
}
void put(std::string s) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    auto s = std::async(get);
    std::thread t(put, s.get());
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I don't know why error occurred when same command is executed in both case." but the output is suggesting a different command is executed from `make`.

Comment: its not the same command, for some reason when you run make it results in `c++     main.cpp   -o main` to be excuted

Comment: The default name of the file `make` refers is `Makefile`, not `MakeFile` with a uppercase `F`.

Comment: Thank you, renaming file as "Makefile" corrected it. I am new to using "Makefile".

Comment: You can see why I had problem as it executed the "make" command even though I had incorrect name for Makefile as "MakeFile".

Comment: Yes, @shubhcodegate, by virtue of its built-in rules, `make` can build some targets without any makefile at all.  In particular, it can build an executable from a correspondingly-named C or C++ (among others) single source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see when you run `make`, the compilation command invocation is missing the `-std=c++11` option that you use when you're compiling your code manually.

You can use

```
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11
```

to have `make` automatically add this option when building `.o` files from `.cpp` files.

You can also provide the `-g` and `-Wall` options the same way.

Comment: as commented by @MikeCAT Renaming as "Makefile" helped. thank you